# How do I disable logging in Jersey 2.x

Tags: java, jersey, client-server, jersey-2.0, grizzly

Currently I'm running Jersey 2.14 (and Grizzly 2.16), though I don't see much difference in newer/older versions regarding logging.

I'm trying to disable message like the following:

```
INFO: 2 * Server responded with a response on thread Grizzly-worker(15)
2 < 201
2 < Location: somewhere
```

From whenever I do, well, anything in a production environment. I even have a barebones class that I thought would hide the method for client and server:

```
@Provider
public class MyLoggingFilter extends LoggingFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext context) throws IOException
    {
        // Do nothing.
        //super.filter(context);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Provider
public class MyLoggingFilter extends LoggingFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException
    {
        // Do nothing.
        //super.filter(context);
    }
}
```

It should be noted that these methods are getting hit, as I found out via trace statements.

Is there some ServerProperty, or other toggleable option, I'm not seeing that is responsible for this so I can turn this off during production?

Thanks!

Comment: LoggingFilter is not registered by default so you have to register it explicitly somewhere. Can you show us your Application subclass (the place where you register resources and providers)? Plus, your custom logging filters should also override filter methods for responses – the log you're seeing is a logged response, not a request.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
Because of the

```
@Provider
```

decoration, the LoggingFilter was being registered automatically. By removing it, I was able to control the logging and thus disable the logging messages.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.xml and/or Application class. Jersey logging filter if added in web.xml will be:

```
  <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

If configured as a Application class it will be included in the class extending org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.